# Convert couple foreachers to linq

Tags: c#

So I have this code and the thing is, that in my project it has to be written with linq expressions and I have no clue how to do that, because there are two lists. Any ideas?

```
public void GetLecturersWorkloadStatistics(List<Student> studentList, List<Lecturer> lecturerList)
{
    foreach (Lecturer lecturer in lecturerList)
    {
        foreach (Student student in studentList)
        {
            if (lecturer.ModuleName == student.ModuleName &&
                lecturer.LastName == student.LecturerLastName &&
                lecturer.FirstName == student.LecturerFirstName)
            {
                lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as told, i've done the inner one with linq, but I've no clue what to do next.

```
public void GetLecturersWorkloadStatistics(List<Student> studentList, List<Lecturer> lecturerList)
{
    foreach (Lecturer lecturer in lecturerList)
    {
        studentList = (from student in studentList
            where lecturer.ModuleName == student.ModuleName &&
                  lecturer.LastName == student.LecturerLastName &&
                  lecturer.FirstName == student.LecturerFirstName
            select student).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Break it down into multiple steps. Tackle the inner foreach first, then tackle the outer one, using the LINQ expression that you came up with for the inner loop.

Comment: @itsme86 I don't know how to write that, that's why I'm asking

Comment: I would argue though, that I find LINQ code that has side-effects (altering `lecturer.Credits`) distasteful.

Comment: You don't even know how to write the inner one? You said the problem was that you were confused because there were 2. Ignore the outer one for now. Leave it as a foreach loop until you've completed the inner loop conversion.

Comment: It doesn't have to have side-effects.  The sum could simply be projected into the target collection.

Comment: @itsme86 I'm gonna write inner one in a couple minutes, but im gonna be stuck.

Comment: Your code describes a JOIN. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: LINQ is best for creating new lists or tables, e.g. if you were returning a new list of lecturers with the values properly updated. But you're not doing that, you're updating in place; LINQ is not very good for this. What is wrong with the nested loops that you have?

Comment: @itsme86 I've updated the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nested foreach such that for each element of list 1 you consider all elements of list 2, this calls for a cartesian product in LINQ which is very easy to do with the LINQ syntax :

```
var LecturersToUpdate = from lecturer in lecturerList
       from student in studentList 
       // 2 from clauses one after the other will give the cartesian product of the lists
       where lecturer.ModuleName == student.ModuleName &&
              lecturer.LastName == student.LecturerLastName &&
              lecturer.FirstName == student.LecturerFirstName 
      // After there where we only get the pair of lecturer/student in the cartesian that match your condition, we stop the query there with a select, we could select both the lecturer and student in a new object but here i'm only grabing the lecturer as that's all you're using in the logic of your foreach
     select lecturer;

foreach(var lect in LecturersToUpdate)
{
    lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits;
}
```

Your updated version was on the right track, you simply needed the additional from clause to get all the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
(from lecturer in lecturerList
from student in studentList
where
    lecturer.ModuleName == student.ModuleName &&
    lecturer.LastName == student.LecturerLastName &&
    lecturer.FirstName == student.LecturerFirstName
select lecturer)
.ToList()
.ForEach(lecturer => lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits)
```

Use two `from` statements the way I did to get a cartesian product of the rows of the two datasets.  With the `where` clause, this becomes equivalent to a database join operation.

I used `ForEach` to do an in-place update of the data.  That method only works on lists, so I had to call `ToList()`.

Make sure you understand @itsme86's comment about side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

My C# is a bit rusty, but here's a way using extension method LINQ notation:

```
lecturerList
    .SelectMany(lecturer => studentList, Tuple.Create)
    .Where((lecturer, student) =>
        lecturer.ModuleName == student.ModuleName &&
        lecturer.LastName   == student.LecturerLastName &&
        lecturer.FirstName  == student.LecturerFirstName)
    .Select((l, s) => l)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(lecturer => lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits);
```

Just like @user2023861, you're basically creating a list of all possible tuples ("cartesian product"):

```
(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), ..., (lecturers.Length() - 1, students.Length() - 1)
```

Then applying the `Where` filter. Then condensing it back into a list of lecturers only.

---

Another idea is to use `Join`:

```
lecturerList
    .Join(studentList,
        lecturer => Tuple.Create(
            lecturer.ModuleName,
            lecturer.LastName,
            lecturer.FirstName),
        student => Tuple.Create(
            student.ModuleName,
            student.LecturerLastName,
            student.LecturerFirstName),
        (lecturer, student) => lecturer);
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(lecturer => lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits);
```

---

If you first sort your data, you can avoid the `O(N^2)` behavior of this and make this much faster for large `N` by making use of early exits. Most sort algorithms are less than `O(N^2)` and with early exiting, you get performance like `O(N log N)`.

Of course, this is only worth it if your dataset is truly large. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method body to use a combination of a `Enumerable.Join` and `Enumerable.All` to make it happen in one line

```
<!-- language: c# -->
lecturerList.Join(studentList, lecturer => new {lecturer.ModuleName, LecturerLastName = lecturer.LastName, LecturerFirstName = lecturer.FirstName}, student=> new {student.ModuleName, student.LecturerLastName, student.LecturerFirstName}, (lecturer, student) => lecturer).All(lecturer=> {lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits; return true;}
```

Comment: you can replace the Enumerable.All with Enumerable.ForEach as shown in @user2023861's answer